# How to extern Class objects C++ MFC

Tags: c++, class, object, mfc, extern

I am working on MFC SDI application, in which I include one C++ generic class, but I have a problem and am stuck on it.

I have a generic C++ class in `Tree.h` and its implementation `Tree.cpp`, as well as two more classes, say `a_Class.h` and `b_Class.h`.

The problem is:

I am making an instance of `Tree.h` in `a_Class.cpp` like this:

```
Tree *obj = new Tree()
```

I declared it it globally. Now, I want to use this very same object in `b_Class`.

For this I use the `extern` keywork, in `b_Class.cpp` as follows:

```
extern Tree *obj;
```

This run fine, but it doesn't use the same object. In the background, it declares separate objects.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description it sounds like it should work. You might rewrite it differently, in a_Class.cpp add global function:

```
static Tree* obj = new Tree();
Tree* GetTreeObj() {
   return obj;
}
```

in b_Class.h add:

```
extern Tree* GetTreeObj();
```

then use GetTreeObj() to retrieve Tree pointer

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I wrote it. and run the same problem accoured.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Like step into GetTreeObj() and investigate variables contents? I also assume you use the same include "Tree.h" in both files.

Comment: Actually, my old way was not working. debugging is helpful a lot. i'll recommend this thing that you give me to others. THANKS A LOT.  you solve my problem.